# Accept only numbers and decimal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello im creating a directive in angularjs that only accepts positive numbers and decimal, and other charecters that arent numbers (ex: +, -, abc...) will me removed.

First i tried using:

```
var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

And it works but doesnt accept decimal numbers, so i use:

```
transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/g, '');
```

What im doing wrong in my code? can someone check it please.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply remove non numbers, non decimal point, non newlines, and non comma?  If so you can use a super simple regex:

```
[^0-9.,\n]+  //global, multiline, replace with blank string
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK0dB2/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[0-9]*$/
```

`^` : Start on the begin.

`[0-9]*` : All number.

`$` : Finish at the end.